# How to schedule Motion detection

Tags: security, scheduled-tasks, motion-detection

I've just discovered [Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) and it works like a charm.. My only problem is that I'd like it to be active only during night-time, but there's no parameter for scheduling..

I think I could write a program that would control Motion via its ["HTTP API"](http://www.lavrsen.dk/twiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionHttpAPI#Detection_Commands), but I was wondering if someone had already done that, or if there's an alternative solution.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this simple task, Motion's HTTP API can be used directly with wget or similar..
Straight from the [FAQ](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_make_time_based_motion_settings_63):

```
0 9 * * * root /usr/bin/lwp-request http://localhost:8080/0/detection/start > /dev/null 
0 18 * * * root /usr/bin/lwp-request http://localhost:8080/0/detection/pause > /dev/null
```

Comment: Note that this pauses the motion capture, but does not turn off the camera or the live feed.  Killing motion turns off the camera.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cron`:

```
crontab -e
```

then put in it:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/motion 
0 8 * * * /usr/bin/killall motion
```

I'm assuming that you want to open "motion" at midnight everyday, and that motion path is /usr/bin/motion: custom this crontab to your needs and it'll do the trick.

Comment: You'll also need to add an entry to stop motion during the day.

0 8 * * * killall motion

Comment: @Chris Nava: Oops...you're right! But instead of "killall" the full path must be used. Usually /usr/bin/killall

Comment: Well that's quite "brutal" but I'll try it out, thanks :)

Comment: I take that back, Motion handles SIGTERMs nicely :)

Comment: I didn't get it: it works?

Comment: @dag279: yes it works :) Although there's another method too, I'll add it as another answer for completeness...

Comment: @Joril: of course the method you posted as an answer is better suited for this situation. My answer is a generic way to do almost...everything! ("Ehy mama, can you please wake me up at 6 a.m.?" "Of course" "crontab -e : 0 6 * * * /usr/bin/wake_up_son")

Comment: If this were a production system I would avoid killall and instead log the process ID of motion and kill just that.  If it's a home machine I doubt you'll run another process named motion unknowingly.